# Time triggered Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, timer, azure-functions

I have created a time triggered azure function to perform certain task, I'm using dependency injection to call Business layer method.But I'm bit confused and stuck how can I use the dependent reference variable inside Run method and call BL method as Run is static method.

```
public class FunctionAccount
{
    private IDeleteAccount _deleteAccount;
    public FunctionAccount(IDeleteAccount deleteAccount)
    {
        _deleteAccount = deleteAccount;
    }

     [FunctionName("FunctionDAccount")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger(GlobalConstant.DeleteAccountTimer)] TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        _deleteAccount .DeletePastYearsUsers(); // This is what I want to do, but as Run method is static I'm not able to do so
        Log.Information($"Function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }


}
```

Comment: `Run` is not required to be a static method anymore

Comment: If you are using DI with Azure Function then you don’t need the entrypoint to be static.

Comment: ahhh , thanks a lot I'll try it, is there any changes that needs to be done as I'm using DI or I can just use as it is ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned (putting it as an answer for visibility) removing the static method will allow you to make use of DI in your functions. You should not need to make any other changes to the structure of the functions once you have setup the DI container and the function class's constructor to accept the injected services.